# Issue when viewing graph in Neo4j

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I just started with Neo4j and I'm trying some examples datasets but sometimes I can't visualize graph properly.

For example : http://neo4j.com/blog/fun-with-beer-and-graphs/

With the following query, I got the same answer but no graph :

```
START
    duvel=node:node_auto_index(name=”Duvel”),
    orval=node:node_auto_index(name=”Orval”)
MATCH p = AllshortestPaths( duvel-[*]-orval )
return p;
```

It seems that the writer is using a graph viewer, see screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOPY9.jpg

Can someone tell me more about this ? What do I need to visualize graph?

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is based on oldier versions of Neo4j.

Check :

1. Your Neo4j version
2. It is using legacy indexing, so did you added auto_indexing in your neo4j.properties ?

Edit: Referencing your last commend, (I get some problems with my mobile to reply to comments)

You should then uncomment # node_auto_indexing

Comment: I use Neo4j 1.9.8 to get the same interface as the demo and for the legacy indexing, here's my settings : # Autoindexing

# Enable auto-indexing for nodes, default is false
#node_auto_indexing=true

# The node property keys to be auto-indexed, if enabled
#node_keys_indexable=name,age

# Enable auto-indexing for relationships, default is false
#relationship_auto_indexing=true

# The relationship property keys to be auto-indexed, if enabled
#relationship_keys_indexable=name,age  Is there something wrong? Thank you

Comment: You have to remove the hash signs `#` those are comment chars. and add the right properties (like name) etc. Then you have to reimport the data.